# Hibernate Search Filter not having expected results with Enum

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I'm using hibernate search 3.4, and I'm running in to a small problem. I have a filter I'm attempting to use (`CourseStatusFilterFactory`), but every time I enable it, no results are returned. I have another filter that works without issues (`DeletedFilterFactory`), so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Here is the object I am trying to search:

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Indexed
@FullTextFilterDefs({
    @FullTextFilterDef(name = "statusFilter", impl = CourseStatusFilterFactory.class, cache = FilterCacheModeType.NONE),
    @FullTextFilterDef(name = "deletedCourse", impl = DeletedFilterFactory.class, cache = FilterCacheModeType.NONE)})
public class Course extends LightEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 21L;
    @Id
    @DocumentId
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Field(name = "title", index = Index.TOKENIZED, store = Store.YES)
    private String title;
    @Field(name = "coursestatus", index = Index.TOKENIZED, store = Store.YES)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private CourseStatus status;}
```

Any my FilterFactory:

```
public class CourseStatusFilterFactory {

private CourseStatus status;

public void setStatus(CourseStatus status) {
    this.status = status;
}

@Key
public FilterKey getKey() {
    StandardFilterKey key = new StandardFilterKey();
    key.addParameter(status);
    return key;
}

@Factory
public Filter getFilter() {
    String statusString = new EnumBridge().objectToString(this.status);
    Query query = new TermQuery(new Term("coursestatus", statusString));
    CachingWrapperFilter cachingWrapperFilter = new CachingWrapperFilter(new QueryWrapperFilter(query));
     return cachingWrapperFilter;
}}
```

and to enable my filter:

```
persistenceQuery.enableFullTextFilter("statusFilter").setParameter("status", CourseStatus.PUBLISHED);
```

When debugging the code, I can see that my query in the filter does get set to "coursestatus:PUBLISHED", but I still have 0 results, even though there should be dozens.

Any ideas of where to start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the help of some people in the [hibernate forum](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1011428&p=2446063) I was able to fix the problem.

I needed to change

```
@Field(name = "coursestatus", index = Index.TOKENIZED, store = Store.YES)
```

to

```
@Field(name = "coursestatus", index = Index.UN_TOKENIZED, store = Store.YES)
```